# static const member of struct uninitializable

Tags: c++

I have a struct, that looks something like

```
struct MyStruct {
    static const std::vector<CustomStruct> someConstValues;
};

const std::vector<CustomStruct> MyStruct::someConstValues = {
    CustomStruct(0),
    CustomStruct(1)
};
```

The definition of the static member takes place outside of the struct since otherwise i get `error: in-class initialization of static data member 'const std::vector<CustomStruct> MyStruct::someConstValues' of non-literal type`.

But in the example above i get `multiple definition of 'MyStruct::someConstValues'` `...` `first defined here`.

How i can i tell the compiler to accept my `static const std::vector<CustomStruct>`?

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre], this is missing too much information. My best guess is that you put both the declaration and definition into a header file, which is included in multiple other files?

Comment: Yes i included the definition in the header file. That solves my problem thank you,